# Transforming a R Dataframe by spreading a single column into multiple columns?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R as below

```
id  Var1    Var2
A   1       A1
A   2       A2
A   3       A3
A   4       A4
A   5       A5
B   1       B1
B   2       B2
B   3       B3
```

How do I transform it into the structure like this below

```
ID  Var1    Var2    Var1    Var2    Var1    Var2    Var1    Var2    Var1    Var2
A   1       A1      2       A2      3       A3      4       A4      5       A5
B   1       B1      2       B2      3       B3      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

Comment: Is it OK to have same column names in your desired output?

Comment: Yes. Same column names are fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
> library(data.table)
> dcast(setDT(Data), id~Var1, value.var=c('Var1', 'Var2'))
   id Var1.1_1 Var1.1_2 Var1.1_3 Var1.1_4 Var1.1_5 Var2_1 Var2_2 Var2_3 Var2_4 Var2_5
1:  A        1        2        3        4        5     A1     A2     A3     A4     A5
2:  B        1        2        3       NA       NA     B1     B2     B3     NA     NA
```